# Answer to "Which version of the Google Maps APIs is currently used when I specify v=2, v=2.x, or v=2.s"?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm looking for the answer to the question that is no longer in the Google Maps API FAQ, the link target to https://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/faq.html#versionaliases is not available.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20100208205838/http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/faq.html#versionaliases (links to another missing doc -> API group)

Comment: You should probably express this in the form of a "just the question" and remove the waffle about how it used to be answered somewhere else.

Comment: how exactly can we help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the versioning information for the V2 API here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIChangelog